# Linq not returning values when using Select to new Object

Tags: linq

I am trying to get a list of objects out of a linq query. Below my classes

```
public partial class FuelBenefit
    {
        public int FuelBenefitId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VehicleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> QuantityByCicle { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UOMId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateStart { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateEnd { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }

public partial class FuelAmountEmployeeCycle
    {
        public int FuelAmountEmployeeCicleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CycleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Balance { get; set; }
}
```

and Query. I don't get an error but no results.

```
 var y = (from e in db.FuelBenefits
                        where e.Active == true 
                        select new FuelAmountEmployeeCycle
                        {
                            CycleId = 1, 
                            EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                            Amount = e.QuantityByCicle,
                            Balance = e.QuantityByCicle
                        });
```

When i do this

```
var y = (from e in db.FuelBenefits
                            where e.Active == true 
                            select e );
```

I do get results.

I have another project where I do this and it works, not sure why this time is not working.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you try adding `ToList()` after the closing parenthesis at the end, and see if it changes anything?

Comment: I tried exactly the same code, I got same result without any problem. There is nothing wrong with this LINQ. However you mentioned Jquery but I can't see any Client-Side code/relations. (It might be the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var y = (from e in db.FuelBenefits
                    where e.Active == true 
                    select new FuelAmountEmployeeCycle
                    {
                        CycleId = 1, 
                        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                        Amount = e.QuantityByCicle,
                        Balance = e.QuantityByCicle
                    });
```

This query isn't running until it reaches to the ToList() code.

You should write it like this:

```
 var y = (from e in db.FuelBenefits
                    where e.Active == true 
                    select new FuelAmountEmployeeCycle
                    {
                        CycleId = 1, 
                        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                        Amount = e.QuantityByCicle,
                        Balance = e.QuantityByCicle
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = db.FuelBenefits.Where(f => f.Active == true)
                   .Select(f => new FuelAmountEmployeeCycle
                   {
                       CycleId = 1,
                       EmployeeId = f.EmployeeId,
                       Amount = f.QuantityByCicle,
                       Balance = f.QuantityByCicle
                   })
                   .ToList();
```